# How to have C++ string literals in template function?

Tags: c++, string-literals

Can someone help me write this function so it works for wide and narrow characters? I've hard coded some string literals as narrow characters (8 bit).

How do I create width neutral string literals that are narrow or wide depending on the the template parameters?

```
template<typename OS, typename T1, typename T2>
OS& operator<<(OS& os, pair<T1,T2> p)
{
    return os << "(" << p.first << "," << p.second << ")";
}
```

This works in clang++ V5.0.1 Clang & g++ 7.1:

```
cout << "pair{3.2, \"hello\"}=" << pair{3.2, "hello"} << endl;
```

I'm surprised. This works too, but is it standard and proper?

```
wcout << L"wcout pair{3.2, \"hello\"}=" << pair{3.2, L"hello"} << endl;
```

Thanks

Siegfried

Comment: The `wcout` statement is formally standard, in that wide streams support output of `char const*`. It's an ungood idea because with g++ and Visual C++ in Windows those narrow strings are always assumed to be Windows ANSI encoded. Which for modern Unicode based apps essentially means that they're restricted to the ASCII subset of Unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string literal's character type is determined by the prefix specified in front of the opening quote of the literal (or lack of a prefix). You cannot specify that prefix dynamically, so the type of a string literal cannot be based on a template.

However, for single characters at least, you can use the [`std::basic_ios::widen()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/widen) method to convert a `char` to the `ostream`'s specified `CharT` type at runtime (dependant on the stream's current locale), eg:

```
template<typename OS, typename T1, typename T2>
OS& operator<<(OS& os, const pair<T1,T2> &p)
{
    return os << os.widen('(') << p.first << os.widen(',') << p.second << os.widen(')');
}
```